# print writing to file from a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, thread-safety

I wrote the following test sample:

```
def initialize():
    data_handler.main()
    print("Initialization Complete")

def test():
    time.sleep(5)
    print('testing')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=initialize).start()
    threading.Thread(target=test).start()
```

The  data_handler module reads a few csv files, modifies them and creates a few statistics. However, instead of the program printing 'testing' to the console, somehow it ends up adding the line 'testing' to one of the files the data_handling module is modifying. I tested it multiple times and it happens every time, although to a different file every time.

I'm trying to figure out how the standard output is redirected to a file and why.

Comment: Have you tried threading.Lock along with print('testing', file=sys.stdout)?

Comment: Clue could be in the data_handler. That module may be hijacking the standard out.

Comment: Using print('testing', file=sys.stdout) didn't fix it. Putting the statement in a lock did seem to fix it, but I'm still not sure why this was happening in the first place. Could it be due to the data_handler module using fileinput.input?